# threejs set transparent color

Tags: three.js, webgl

I would like to be able to set a given vertices transparency by its color (defined in the vertColors array) so that on a single mesh I can have areas of varying opacity.

Is there a simple way to make all vertices that are defined as a certain color transparent?

One thought I had; Would it be possible to extend/alter the shader of MeshBasicMaterial to define all black areas as transparent?

Alternatively might I be able to pass the output of this material into a second shader to do this?

```
const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

const vertPositions = createVertPositions(); //Float32Array of positions
const vertColors = createVertColors(); //Float32Array of colors

geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertPositions, 3));
geometry.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertColors, 3));

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.5,
  side: THREE.BackSide,
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you implemented any of your ideas and they did not work?

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the docs that you can use the `.alphaMap` property of the [MeshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshBasicMaterial) to achieve what you're looking to do. Note that with the WebGLRenderer you will use the green channel as your alpha value (RGB) rather than the alpha channel.

As you loop to create your color array you could simultaneously be producing your alphaMap array dependent on the values of your colors. Then you'll need to turn that array into a texture and assign it to the `.alphaMap` property.